# document.getElementById.show() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, if-statement

I have a form. When a user clicks a list item and selects a "size value", it is given a class of selected, and then the user can submit the form.

The part that I'm trying to figure out is that when no size is selected (and thus no list item has a class of "selected") the form won't be submitted, and instead the error message shows. I'm having trouble getting this to work and the error message to show, as the form still just submits.

Currently I'm getting an error telling me that `document.getElementById("errormessage").show()` is not a function.

Does anyone know why this is happening? And can anyone help me with my code to get it to work the way I want to?

```js
.on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("es-value");
  var i = x.length;
  var selected = false;
  while (i--) {
    if (x[i].hasAttribute("selected")) {
      selected = true;
    }
  }
  if (selected == false) {
    //Displays error
    document.getElementById("errormessage").show();
  } else {
    $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form').submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li class="size-value"></li>
        <li class="size-value"></li>
        <li class="size-value"></li>
        <li class="size-value"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<div id="errormessage">Please select a size</div>
<div class="mt10">
  <input type="submit" class="modalAddToBagButton">
</div>
```

Comment: Because native DOM elements do not have a `show()` function, you are thinking of a jQuery function

Comment: `.show()` needs to be done on a jquery object use `$('#errormessage')` to get the element - getElementById is native js and will give you a dom object

Comment: You should decide to either use jQuery or Javascript otherwise you'll keep making these mistakes...

Comment: provide your code  via codepen or other similar coding tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up `Javascript` and `Jquery` functions.

Update from

```
document.getElementById("errormessage").show();
```

to

```
$("#errormessage").show();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("errormessage").style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: It is not ok to keep styles in JS. Better use hidden attribute.
Also it seems that `errormessage` shoud be invisible by default.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to jquery show method. For that you need jquery object. Replace 
`document.getElementById("errormessage").show();`

with

```
$("#errormessage").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`show` is a JQuery function. when using `getElementById` you get the javascript element, not the JQuery one. Use `$('#errormessage')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Better use native JS hidden attribute. In your HTML replace that line

```
<div id="errormessage">Please select a size</div>
```

with that

```
<div id="errormessage" hidden>Please select a size</div>
```

And than in JS

```
document.getElementById("errormessage").hidden = false;
```

For submit use

```
form.addEventListener("submit", callback);
```

form - your form element,
also use

```
btn.addEventListener("click", callback);`
```

btn - your button, `.closest()` and '.find()' replace with `el.querySelectorAll()` and chain it in necessary order. Always cache your getElementByWhatever or querySelectors in var and reuse it.
Also in your code it is no need to check every `x[i].hasAttribute("selected")` if it is at least one item with selected you can end your loop with `break;`.